# How to hide protected operating system files in file manager search?

Tags: windows

I have a used the attrib +s +h command in cmd to hide a folder with personal pictures and other personal documents, however the folder and documents still show up in the search in file explorer. I have used indexing options to hide the files and folder from windows 10 search, however it does effect file explorer's search.

Comment: An administrator can find any file on your system.  Hiding a file isn't a good approach.  If you want to hide files use a VeraCrypt container or similar approach.

Comment: hiding a file only affects how it's shown in explorer. Indexing is for accelerating searching. It doesn't mean that searching is impossible to find a file without an index. You need to encrypt the file if you want to prevent others from reading it

Comment: I do not suggest to change the permissions of the system folders/files. And as usual, non-admin users should have no permission to modify the system files.

Answer (score 0):

your options are

1. Create new partition of ntfs/fat32 and mount them when necessary via diskmgmt.msc (same performance)
2. to create VHD image files and mount them when necessary (using vhdattach - almost similar performance )
3. to create truecrypt/veracrypt container and mount them when necessary ( heavy lag in performance due to encryption/decryption )
4. to create as TAR file, using 7zip ( update/whenever necessary)